# Como Bloquear Boton asp c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como puedo bloquear un formulario en `.aspx`?

Lo que pasa, es que cuando mi botón registra puedo volver a presionar y puede registrar dos veces como la imagen, es decir yo quiero que cuando el aviso salga solo tenga la opción de presionar aceptar .

**Este es mi HTML :**

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnnoConforme" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" style="font-weight:bold;margin-right: 5px;" Text="Registrar" OnClick="BtnnoConforme_Click" Font-Bold="True" />
```

**Este es mi código de servidor:**

```
                         cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechacumplimientotarea", SqlDbType.Date);
                         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ERROR", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
                         cmd.Parameters["@fechacumplimientotarea"].Value = txtfechaoculta.Text;
                         cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                         cn.Open();

                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                         message = (string)cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;


                         // lblErrorMsg.Text = message;

                         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message, "..::Aviso del Sistema::..");
                         BtnnoConforme.Enabled = false;
                         cn.Close();
                         Response.Redirect("FrmLogeo.aspx");
                         TxtMontoPagado.Text = "";
                         txtNumeroRecibo.Text = "";
                         TxtFecha.Text = "";
                     }
```

**Esto es lo que muestra mi aplicación:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La página que estas mostrando en la imagen se llama `FrmLogeo.aspx` ?

Comment: Ni bien le haces click usa la propiedad enabled y lo seteas en false

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez no se llama FrmAtenderTarea

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti si no con enabled ni false funciona

Comment: OK. lo que pasa es que en el código que muestras, se hace un `Response.Redirect` a otra página y esto puede influir en el resultado que estas esperando. Me puedes aclarar un poco para que usas esa instrucción?

Comment: Estimado, quizá si coloca el BtnnoConforme.Enabled = false; antes de mostrar la ventana del mensaje, o sea inmediatamente despues de hacer click en el botón. Saludos.

Comment: También es extraño que una aplicación Web estes utilizando `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show`. Esta instrucción solo la deberías utilizar para aplicaciones Windows no Web.

Comment: Si claro lo utilizo que cuando registren automaticamente se valla a la pagina de inicio entre este caso FrmLogeo para eso utilizo

Comment: @Pierro, tu aplicación tiene un error grave cuando utilizas `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show`, dame unos minutos y te lo trato de explicar en un respuesta.

Comment: Esta bien @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez Muchas Gracias te espero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, le dejo una alternativa para hacerlo con javascript:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnnoConforme" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" style="font-weight:bold;margin-right: 5px;" Text="Registrar" OnClick="BtnnoConforme_Click" Font-Bold="True" onclick="Desabilitar()" />
```

El javascript sería:

```
<script>

function Desabilitar() {
    document.getElementById("<%=BtnnoConforme.ClientID%>").enabled = false;
}
</script>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Deshabilitar con H, una pequeña corrección, buen aporte, saludos!

Comment: @fernando Campos  lo coloce tal como me pusiste me salio un error cuando di:
este mensaje  :

Error del analizador

Descripción: Error al analizar el recurso requerido para dar servicio a esta solicitud. Revise los detalles de error de análisis específicos y modifique el archivo de código fuente en consecuencia. 

Mensaje de error del analizador: La etiqueta contiene atributos 'onclick' duplicados.

Error de código fuente:

Comment: OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="Deshabilitar()" La funcion que deshabilita el botón de forma local se debe llamar OnClientClick ya que la otra se ejecuta es en el servidor

Comment: @Softwarelover si pero ahora me sale este error :
La colección de controles no puede modificarse porque el control contiene bloques de código (por ej. <% ... %>).

Comment: @Pierro Sugiero probar con: document.getElementById("BtnnoConforme").disabled = true;       me funcion al igual que con:  document.getElementById("<%=BtnnoConforme.ClientID%>").enabled = false;

Answer (score 0):

```
BtnnoConforme.Enabled = false;
```

Pone ese código arriba del todo, antes de ejecutar la Query

Answer (score 0):

Quizá esto te pueda servir.

Agrega un estilo a css por ejemplo:

```
    <style>
        .hide {
            visibility: hidden;

        }

    </style>
```

y en el back agregale este estilo al inicio de tu metodo:

```
btnGuardar.CssClass = "hide";
```

Igual y esto te pueda funcionar.

Te dejo el ejemplo funcionando.

http://www.lomart.mx/blog/2017/03/21/ocultar-boton-codebehind-desarrollo-sitio-web/

Answer (score 0):

Cuando trabajas con Paginas Web de `ASPX`, trata al máximo de no usar controles o funcionalidades de `WinForm`, por que seguramente no te van a dar el funcionamiento correcto.

Con el código que tienes en este momento, el mensaje que intentas mostrar al usuario se está ejecutando en el servidor, esto que significa?. Pues que si una persona intenta acceder a la URL de tu aplicación en este momento por ejemplo: http://tu-pc/FrmAtenderTarea.aspx y luego presiona el botón de registrar, esa persona no va a ver el mensaje, y esto por que?. Pues los mensajes va a estar apareciendo es en tu PC (o sea en el servidor) y no en el navegador del usuario que llamo la aplicación.

Esta es una de las razones por la cual tu página no se bloquea, por que la alerta no la está lanzando el navegador (como debería ser), sino que la alerta la esta lanzando el proceso del servidor web sobre su propio sistema operativo.

Me podría extender mas explicándote otras implicaciones que tiene lo que estas haciendo, pero creo que lo importante ahora es corregir tu aplicación, que seria de la siguiente manera:

**Primero**

Elimina todas las referencias de tu proyecto que tengas a `System.Windows.Forms`

**Segundo**

Corrige tú código de la siguiente manera:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fechacumplimientotarea", SqlDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ERROR", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
cmd.Parameters["@fechacumplimientotarea"].Value = txtfechaoculta.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
message = (string)cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;
cn.Close();

// lblErrorMsg.Text = message;
//BtnnoConforme.Enabled = false;            

TxtMontoPagado.Text = "";
txtNumeroRecibo.Text = "";
TxtFecha.Text = "";

var scriptText = "alert('" + message + "'); location.href='http://tu-url-de-login';";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "MessageScript", scriptText, true);
```